# Python- last item in a for loop cannot be added to a dictionary

Tags: python

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
numbers = ['judge1','judge2','judge3','judge4','judge5']
dictionary = {}
for letter in letters:
    for number in numbers:
        roundDictionary[letter] = {number : None}
```

I want the dictionary be:

```
dictionary = {'a' : {'1' : None, '2' : None, '3' : None, '4' : None, '5' : 
None}}
```

and so on for each letter but the dictionary is only displaying the item in the last position of the list like this:

```
{'a': {'5': None}, 'b': {'5': None}, 'c': {'5': None}, 'd': {'5': None}, 'e': {'5': None}, 'f': {'5': None}}
```

How can I get it to add all the numbers list to the dictionary? Thanks

Comment: Keys must be unique. Inside the second loop you keep overwriting the value stored against `letter`

Comment: `letters_dict = dict(zip(letters,[dict.fromkeys(numbers) for _ in range(len(letters))]))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are reassigning the value to the key in each loop. Effectively you are overwriting it every time, which is why you only see the last value. Try this instead.

```py
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
dictionary = {}

for letter in letters:
    for number in numbers:
        if (letter not in dictionary):
            dictionary[letter] = {}
        dictionary[letter][number] = None
```

Edit: The comment from @Joran Beasley came in while posting this. His method is much cleaner than using nested loops and checking for key existence.